# How to know if openpyxl is using defusedxml?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to read xlsx files, and noted the recommendation to use defusedxml to guard against certain security attacks. My understanding is that openpyxl will use defusedxml anytime it finds it installed in the current environment, but I would like a more positive way to check that defusedxml is being used before I open a workbook, so I can fail early in case some user of my code has not installed the package (or possibly some incompatible version is installed, not sure that is possible now but could be in the future?).

Is there a way to programatically interrogate openpyxl to ask it if it has detected defusedxml and planning to invoke it on next spreadsheet I open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accordingly to this [commit](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/merge_requests/300/diffs), you can use the following code:

```
from openpyxl import DEFUSEDXML
if DEFUSEDXML is True:
    ...
```